# TYPO3 typoscript menu: hide element condition

Tags: typo3

This is my typoscript menu:

```
page.10.variables {
menue = HMENU
menue {
#special = directory
#special.value = 17
wrap = <div id="mobile-header"><div class="bar"></div></div><div class="menu-collapsed"><div id="navigation"><nav class="nav"><ul>|</ul></nav></div></div>
1 = TMENU
1.expAll=1
1 {
      NO {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        # linkWrap = |<span class="underline"></span>
         ATagParams=class="navi"
          }
      RO = 1
      RO {         
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        # linkWrap = |<span class="underline"></span>   
         ATagParams=class="navi"
         }
      ACT = 1
      ACT {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        # linkWrap = |<span class="underline"></span>
        ATagParams=class="navi_active"
        }  

       IFSUB = 1
       IFSUB {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
         linkWrap = |<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         ATagParams=class="navi sub"
            }

     ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB

        SPC = 1
    SPC {
     doNotLinkIt = 1
     doNotShowLink = 1
     allWrap = <div class="space"></div>
    }    
  }

  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul class="nav_list1 subnavi resp">|</ul>
  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
  2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
  3 < .2
  3.wrap = <ul id="subsubnavi">|</ul>
  }


menue2 = HMENU
menue2 {
special = directory
special.value = 62
1 = TMENU
1.expAll=1
1 {
wrap = <div class="box-menue2"><nav class="nav"><ul class="profile_tab">|</ul></nav></div>
      NO {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
         ATagParams=class="navi2"
     stdWrap.dataWrap =<i class="fa fa-{field:tx_iconfont_icon}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     stdWrap.dataWrap.insertData=1
          }
      RO = 1
      RO {         
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        stdWrap.dataWrap =<i class="fa fa-{field:tx_iconfont_icon}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     stdWrap.dataWrap.insertData=1
         ATagParams=class="navi2"
         }
      ACT = 1
      ACT {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     stdWrap.dataWrap =<i class="fa fa-{field:tx_iconfont_icon}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     stdWrap.dataWrap.insertData=1
        ATagParams=class="navi2_active"
        }  

       IFSUB = 1
       IFSUB {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
         linkWrap = |<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         ATagParams=class="navi2 sub"
            }

     ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB

        SPC = 1
    SPC {
     doNotLinkIt = 1
     doNotShowLink = 1
     allWrap = <div class="space"></div>
    }    
  }

  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul class="nav_list">|</ul>
  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
  2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
  3 < .2
  3.wrap = <ul id="subsubnavi">|</ul>
  }


menue3 = HMENU
menue3 {
special = directory
special.value = 57
1 = TMENU
1.expAll=1
1 {
wrap = <div class="box-menue3"><nav class="nav3"><ul class="profile_tab">|</ul></nav></div>
      NO {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
         ATagParams=class="navi2"
     stdWrap.dataWrap =<i class="fa fa-{field:tx_iconfont_icon}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     stdWrap.dataWrap.insertData=1
          }
      RO = 1
      RO {         
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        stdWrap.dataWrap =<i class="fa fa-{field:tx_iconfont_icon}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     stdWrap.dataWrap.insertData=1
         ATagParams=class="navi2"
         }
      ACT = 1
      ACT {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
     stdWrap.dataWrap =<i class="fa fa-{field:tx_iconfont_icon}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     stdWrap.dataWrap.insertData=1
        ATagParams=class="navi2_active"
        }  

       IFSUB = 1
       IFSUB {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
         stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
         stdWrap.cObject.field = subtitle // title
         ATagBeforeWrap = 1
         linkWrap = |
         ATagParams=class="navi sub"
            }

     ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB

        SPC = 1
    SPC {
     doNotLinkIt = 1
     doNotShowLink = 1
     allWrap = <div class="space"></div>
    }    
  }

  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul class="nav_list">|</ul>
  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
  2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>
  3 < .2
  3.wrap = <ul id="subsubnavi">|</ul>
  }

    FOO2 = HMENU
    FOO2{
   special = directory
   special.value = 18  
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
         NO {   
      wrapItemAndSub = | |*| &nbsp;&nbsp; | |*| &nbsp;&nbsp; |
         }
   }
   }
}
```

I need show some sub element on menu on condition. If some field in db == 0: show one menu element, else: show second. Is it possible ? I hope you understand what I want. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

'condition' is not unique in regards of typoscript.

there are 'conditions' which switch parts of typoscript on and off.

```
[global]
```

these conditions normaly depend on the environment of the page call.

you want a condition depending on database value so you need  to use stdWrap functions which evaluate on data values.
Aside from the big function [`if`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/If/Index.html) which has multiple options there are [`override`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html?highlight=ifempty#override), [`ifEmpty`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html?highlight=ifempty#ifempty) and [`ifBlank`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html?highlight=ifempty#ifblank).

Either you write your alternatives in a COA and wrap each part with its own `if` or you write your typoscript with the default config and do an `override` which is switched on and of with its own `if` wrap.

For a clean typoscript you may use `temp` objects which you can copy and held your usage clean.
**Example:**

```
temp.alternative1 = COA
temp.alternative1 {
    :
}
temp.alternative2 = COA
temp.alternative2 {
    :
}

10 = HMENU
10 {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
     :
     before < temp.alternative1
     before.override < temp.alternative2
     before.override.if.isfalse.field = my_field
  }
}
```